# Insert to SQL Azure through Linked Server very slow

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table on SQL Asure server with no indexes except clustered.
And I insert into this table small amount of data just about 1000 rows and it takes more than 4 minutes. Although, when I do it with SSIS it takes just a second.
This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseName.dbo.tmpOurClients
(KodClient,Name ,ShortName,INN,Boss,contact,Email,Adres,Tel,City_ID,DateLop)
SELECT KodClient,Name ,ShortName,INN,Boss,contact,Email,Adres,Tel,City_ID,DateLop
FROM dbo.OurClients
```

That is how I created the Linked Server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server='Azure',
@srvproduct='',
@provider='sqlncli',
@datasrc='ServerName.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET',
@location='',
@provstr='',
@catalog='db_name'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname='Azure',
@useself='false',
@rmtuser='login@server_name.database.windows.net',
@rmtpassword='password'

EXEC sp_serveroption 'Azure', 'Collation Compatible', true;
```

I've already checked this topic [Linked server to SQL Azure very slow](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/linked-server-to-sql-azure-very-slow) but none of suggestions helped me.

Version of local SQL-Server: *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)*

So, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I insert into this table small amount of data just about 1000 rows and it takes more than 4 minutes*

Remote data modifications through a linked server use the `sp_cursor` model. The effect is similar to issuing 1000 separate single inserts (one for each row). If a round trip takes 250ms, 1000 such trips will take 4 minutes and 10 seconds. Using a bulk loading method such as `bcp` or `SSIS` will generally be more efficient (unless the number of rows to be inserted is tiny).

Another alternative for ad-hoc needs is to build a string containing a single `INSERT` statement with multiple rows in the `VALUES` clause. The statement is then used with `EXECUTE AT`, for example:

```
-- Note local-to-azure table name used, not four-part syntax
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'INSERT dbo.Test VALUES ';

-- Build a list of 1000 numbers to insert    
SELECT @sql += '(' + CONVERT(varchar(11), n) + '),'
FROM dbo.Numbers AS N
WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;

-- Remove trailing comma
SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1);

-- For debugging
PRINT @sql;

-- Execute the finished statement at the remote server;
EXECUTE (@sql) AT AZURE;
```

The constructed insert statement executes at the Azure database, so a **local name** is used for the table (note: building a dynamic insert statement using a four-part target name buys you nothing).

Note that `EXECUTE ... AT` requires `RPC` and `RPC OUT` enabled in the linked server options.

The `VALUES` clause for a plan `INSERT` statement is limited to 1000 elements. There are ways around that (a `VALUES` clause in a CTE does not have that restriction). You could also choose to build 1000-row batches or build single-row insert statements, but if the there is that much data on a regular basis, you would probably be better off using one of the bulk loading methods instead.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I have a process that inserts over 211,000 records into an Azure SQL database. It was taking 2 hours and 15 minutes. Implementing this solution in 1000 record batches with a WHILE loop brought that down to 90 seconds.