# Joining table from Linked Server is very slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, linked-server, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I have a production SQL server and a linked server (Azure SQL Database)

I join two tables to do update

```
Table A - small table A in TempDB that has only 100 rows on SQL Server
Table B - on linked server, is about 90 MB in size and 334,000 rows total
```

When I run below query

```
update A
    set A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB
from #Table A
    join [LinkedServer].[DB].[dbo].[Table] B on
         A.ID = B.ID
```

The update of 100 rows takes about 18 seconds! 1000 or more rows take much more time

I made sure below is true:

```
Column B.ID is indexed
Collation Compatible setting in Linked Server Options is set to "True"
```

I even tried to significantly scale up Azure SQL DB (from 20 DTU to 800 DTU), but the speed of query (100 rows update) went from 18 sec to 8 sec which is still not acceptable

What am I missing ? 
Is there any workarounds in this situation ?

Regards,

Comment: Check out [these](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59328/insert-to-sql-azure-through-linked-server-very-slow) related [questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/linked-server-to-sql-azure-very-slow).

Comment: @LowlyDBA, I tried "Collation Compatible" setting from second link, and will try that crazy workaround from first link. However, I am wondering if there is a simpler way

Answer (score 1):

Put an index on A.ID

Add a <> so it can avoid taking locks

```
update A
    set A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB
from #Table A
join [LinkedServer].[DB].[dbo].[Table] B 
  on A.ID = B.ID 
where A.ColumnA <> B.ColumnB or A.ColumnA is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you capture waits related to this particular query you will see high values for the OLEDB wait type which is common when querying a remote server using linked servers. To my knowledge you cannot avoid that. I have wrote about it [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0016.htm).

You can capture query waits using below script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #before;
 SELECT [wait_type], [waiting_tasks_count], 
 [wait_time_ms], [max_wait_time_ms],
 [signal_wait_time_ms]
 INTO #before
 FROM sys.[dm_db_wait_stats];

 -- Execute test query here

 DECLARE @Rows INT
 SELECT @Rows = 100

 ;WITH Q AS
 (
 SELECT A.StateProvince, A.CountryRegion,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.CountryRegion ORDER BY A.StateProvince, A.CountryRegion) GrpRow
 FROM SalesLT.Address A
 )
 SELECT TOP(@Rows) Q.*
 FROM Q
 WHERE GrpRow <= 1 + CEILING(@Rows * 1.0 / ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CountryRegion) FROM Q))

 -- Finish test query

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #after;
 SELECT [wait_type], [waiting_tasks_count], [wait_time_ms], [max_wait_time_ms],
 [signal_wait_time_ms]
 INTO #after
 FROM sys.[dm_db_wait_stats];

 -- Show accumulated wait time

 SELECT [a].[wait_type], ([a].[wait_time_ms] - [b].[wait_time_ms]) AS [wait_time]
 FROM [#after] AS [a]
 INNER JOIN [#before] AS [b] ON
 [a].[wait_type] = [b].[wait_type]
 ORDER BY ([a].[wait_time_ms] - [b].[wait_time_ms]) DESC;
```

For more ways how to capture specific query waits, please read [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0017.htm).

Look at the query plan, you may also find no indexes are participating on the join.

Can you use SQL Data Sync to keep a copy of the table on the on-premise SQL Server and then create the join with the local copy of the table?